# Testing whether a determinant polynomial is identically zero

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we are given matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ which are $n \times n$ matrices with rational entries and are asked to determine whether the polynomial ${\rm det}(\alpha_1 A_1 + \alpha_2 A_2 + \cdots + \alpha_k A_k)$ is identically zero. How can we do this **deterministically** in polynomial time in $n$ and $k$?

I'm aware that black-box polynomial identity testing is a difficult problem, but then this is not quite a black box.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47362/subspaces-of-singular-matrices.

Comment: An issue here could be that equality in the reals is not decidable. So even in the case of $k=n=1$, you cannot do this. However, you can decide whether or not two numbers are $\epsilon$ close for any non-zero $\epsilon$, which is good enough if you are using something like floats.

Comment: I meant to say that the matrices should have rational entries - have edited this into the question just now.

Comment: suggest migrate to tcs.se. can you elaborate on how this is different than polynomial identity testing? there is a large amt of research on that

Comment: @vzn - this is polynomial identity testing, but it might not be equivalent to "black box" identity testing since there might be hope that the specific structure of the polynomial here could be helpful.

Comment: Since the question has been on this website for a week and has not been answered, it would be great if it were migrated to tcs.se

Comment: To compute the matrix $M=\Sigma_1^k\alpha_i M_i$ requires  $kn^2$ multiplications. The number of additions needed is $n^2(k-1)$. Therefore to compute the entries of $M$,  $n^2(2k-1)$ operations are needed. Now if we can find an algorithm that is polynomial time that will compute the determinant, then we are done. Some polynomial time calculations of a determinant are given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation . Whether or not their are more efficient methods, I do not know.

Comment: @BabyDragon - I'm not sure what "compute the determinant" means in this case. The matrix $\sum_i \alpha_i A_i$ has entries which are not numbers but rather linear functions of the variables $\alpha_i$. Its determinant is thus a polynomial in $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ of degree $n$. So when you say "compute the determinant" do you mean compute each coefficient of this polynomial? The number of these coefficients is exponential in $n$.

Comment: I took the $\alpha_i$ to be rational numbers, the same as the entries of the matrices.

Comment: No, the question is asking how to check whether ${\rm det}(\sum_i \alpha_i A_i)$, which is a polynomial in the variables $\alpha_i$, is identically zero.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a practical problem or a theoretical problem?

If it a practical problem, it looks to me like standard randomized algorithms for black-box polynomial identity testing should suffice to solve this.

Your polynomial is a multivariate polynomial of degree $n$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$.  Pick a set $S$ of real numbers with cardinality $2n$, draw $k$ numbers uniformly at random from $S$, and evaluate the polynomial at those points (substituting the first for $\alpha_1$, the second for $\alpha_2$, and so on).  Check whether the result is non-zero.  By Schwartz-Zippel, either your polynomial is identically zero or else the result will be non-zero with probability $\ge 1/2$.  Thus, we can repeat this test $m$ times.  If we get zero every time, output "the polynomial is identically zero".  Otherwise output "the polynomial is not identically zero".  You'll be wrong with probability at most $1/2^m$.

If you want to have a small seed, use a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator to generator the random numbers needed for this procedure.  Under a suitable cryptographic assumption, this will allow you to use only 128 bits of true randomness (or so).

This should be good enough for all practical applications.  Of course, it doesn't answer the theoretical question of whether this problem has a deterministic polytime algorithm.

Comment: Thanks - but this is a theoretical problem. Mostly, I'm just curious whether "determinant structure" allows you to do identity testing.

Answer (score 2):

This currently **does not** have any deterministic polynomial-time algorithm, not even "whitebox". Moreover, it is expected to be a very hard problem as due to a landmark paper by Kabanets-Impagliazzo [Derandomizing Polynomial Identity Tests …](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/papers/poly_derand.pdf), even showing that it is in NSUBEXP would imply strong circuit lower bounds like permanent has no polynomial-size circuit or that NEXP is not contained in P/poly.

There has been a lot of recent progress especially on a subcase called the "non-commutative" version of this in which we consider the $\alpha_i$ to be non-commuting variables. This was [derandomized (whitebox) recently by GGOW (over C)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03730) and [Ivanyos, Youming Qiao, and Subrahmanyam (over every characteristic fields)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03531).

Another recent work gave [A Deterministic PTAS to approximate the maximum rank of such a linear combination](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v014a003/)